# React hook to wait until the previous call is complete

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am working on a react project which uses hooks. And I was assigned a task

"change the `useInterval` hook, or create a new one (usePoll?). This should operate the same as `useInterval`, but should wait until the `ajax` request is complete before starting the timer".

I am new to react hooks and was looking for a solution for this but could not find. Current `useInterval` function is as follows.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export function useInterval(callback, delay, immediate = true) {
    const savedCallback = useRef();

    // Remember the latest callback.
    useEffect(() => {
        savedCallback.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    // Set up the interval.
    useEffect(() => {
        function tick() {
            savedCallback.current();
        }
        if (delay !== null) {
            if (immediate) {
                tick();
            }

            let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
            return () => clearInterval(id);
        }
    }, [delay]);
}
```

and it use in the program as follows.

```
useInterval(() => {
        get(`/api/v1/streams/1`).then(({ data: { data } }) => {
            setStream(data);
        });
    }, 5000);
```

and I need to change the useInterval function to wait until the ajax request is complete before starting the timer. It would be great if anyone can help me on this. Thanks

Comment: @bkm412 did not get that mate. can you please explain.

Comment: Often times using a useEffect once the data has changed is the best way to handle this in React.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.. it requires calling the `next` function inside of `then` but it should come close to what you're looking for.

```
function useInterval(handler, delay, immediate = true) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let interval

    const start = () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
      interval = setInterval(() => handler(start), delay)
    }

    handler(start)

    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])
}
```

usage:

```
useInterval((next) => {
    get('/api/v1/streams/1').then(data => {
        // tell the timer to begin
        next()
    })
}, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`async\await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to await for first call completes.

Modify internal `useEffect` like so

```
export function useInterval(callback, delay, immediate = true) {
    const savedCallback = useRef();

    // Remember the latest callback.
    useEffect(() => {
        savedCallback.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);
    // Set up the interval.
    useEffect(() => {
        // useEffect doesn't like async callbacks (https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326) so create nested async callback
        (async () => { 
            // Make tick() async
            async function tick() {
                await savedCallback.current();
            }
            if (delay !== null) {
                if (immediate) {
                    await tick();  // Here we should await for tick()
                }

                let id = setInterval(tick, delay);  // Unfortunately setInterval is not async/await compatible. So it will not await for tick
                return () => clearInterval(id);
           }
        })(); // Call nested async function
    }, [delay]);
```

}

And you callback should return `Promise` so `async\await` to work properly

```
useInterval(() => {
    // After .then promise will be resolved, so our useInterval will know about that
    return get(`/api/v1/streams/1`).then(({ data: { data } }) => {
        setStream(data);
    });
}, 5000);
```